# How to identify the element that opened the bootstrap modal?

Tags: twitter-bootstrap

I have three elements that open the same modal dialog using bootstrap modal. I would like to know if there is a way to know which element opened the modal on the `shown` event

```
$('#myModal').on("shown.bs.modal", function () {
    //get the element that opened the modal
    //console.log(event.target.id);
});
```

Is it possible? If so, how?

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/codovations/S9Bp4/2/

Answer (score 2, accepted):

[`event.relatedTarget`](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/event.relatedTarget) worked for me. Pasting this for anyone who might stumble upon the same issue

```
$('#myModal').on("shown.bs.modal", function (evt) {
    //get the element that opened the modal
    console.log(evt.relatedTarget);
});
```

Fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/codovations/S9Bp4/3/